# Android ActionBar Style Not being applied

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I've been trying to change the text color of the tabs and menus in my action bar. I've followed a few of the answered questions on here and looked at the Android developer site. I've made the changes to my code but the theme in my style.xml file is not being applied.

The minSdkVersion specified in my manifest is 19 and I am running on a lollipop device.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/green</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabText" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
    // user swipes between sections.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Why ActionBar? ToolBar exist more than year already.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyActionBarTheme >
```

And use this codes for **Styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/tabtextcolor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle"parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
         <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    </style>

    <style name="tabtextcolor" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this. This does change the theme of the action bar, but it also causes the icon (displayed in the top left of the bar) to stop showing up. Also, the theme seems to be applied across my fragments, i.e. text in my listitem is being changed when it's unrelated to the action bar.

Comment: Hmm, updating as you said doesn't cause the new style to be used, it causes a default style to be used, i.e. as opposed to Holo. This answer doesn't therefore resolve the issue unfortunately.